Conditionals and the difference between them
When I use 2 conditional in the result clause I use either might, could, or would.


If she arrived I would give  her a hug

If she arrived I was going to give her a hug



That's why 1 can refer to what we  might do in the present or it is also possible it refers only to the past; while 2 only refers to the past, not hypothetical situation in the present because I used "was going to" in the result clause?

Your question is a bit confusing, but, no, (1) can't refer to the past. Speaking of a past situation, you would say "If she had arrived I would have given her a hug".

@KateBunting and 2 can't refer to the present?

I was going to implies that the opportunity for doing so is past.

It would be more idiomatic to write 1 as "If she arrives I will give her a hug".
